# How does bazel choose the python version?

Tags: bazel

I'm running a python binary target with `bazel run xxx` and in the target I'm doing `print(sys.version)`. This outputs `Python version 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34)`

When I type the `python` command directly, I get `Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 19:16:38)`

Why/how did bazel choose a different python version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bazel will choose different python versions based on the configuration of the build. If nothing is overriden, bazel will use its default python version. This can be overridden by passing `--python_version=<some_version>` when running a bazel command.

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/python.html#py_binary.python_version
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/120590e2f2b66e5590bf4dc8ebef9c5338984775/python/BUILD#L43

Comment: "If nothing is overriden, bazel will use its default python version" how does that work? where is that default defined?, the link you provided says "default is `_INTERNAL_SENTINEL`" why is that?

Also, it seems the valid values for `python_version` are `PY2` and `PY3`, which Python 3 version? why `3.6.8` in the case of the original question and not `3.7.3`?